# Understanding the spatial resolution of a imaging sensor, should it evenly divide the overall image resolution?

Tags: optics, satellites, imaging

I am reviewing the Landsat 1 satellite, specifically its [Multispectral Scanner (MSS) imaging system](https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/the-multispectral-scanner-system/). The system had the following specifications

```
Sensor type: opto-mechanical
*Spatial Resolution: 68 m X 83 m (commonly resampled to 57 m, or 60 m)
Spectral Range: 0.5 – 1.1 µm
Number of Bands: 4, 5 (Landsat 3 only)
Temporal Resolution: 18 days (L1-L3), 16 days (L4 & L5)
Image Size: 185 km X 185 km
Swath: 185 km
Programmable: no
```

Why doesn't the spatial resolution of the sensor evenly divide the final image resolution? Is the spatial resolution not "locked" to the size of a pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is not a line scan camera in the sense where you have a line of pixels that is captured simultaneously. It sounds more like a "pixel-scan" camera where something is scanning perpendicular to the satellite's direction of motion.

There is overlap between consecutive images as a result and they are removing that overlap so that only "unique" information is being included in their resolution numbers.